# Keeping downstream Puppet git repositories in sync except for ignored directories

Tags: git, puppet

I have a git configuration for our Puppet Dev/Test server that looks like this:

1. Developer has a working directory in his/her /home directory in which changes to configurations are actually made.
2. Changes are pushed from each working directory to a central, bare repository.
3. Changes are then pulled into the Development directory which is where testing occurs.
4. Changes are then pulled into the Production repository. However, in the Production repository I want to ignore the manifests/ directory which has host-specific information from Development. The idea being that the Production repository would either contain other manifests or none leaving the manifests to be under control elsewhere.

When I remove the directory from the repository and then add an entry to the .gitignore file `git status` tells me that the Production repository has changes that need to be committed (the deleted directory) and is one commit ahead of the Development repository.

What I have found is that by adding the directory to .gitignore while leaving the directory on the filesystem alleviates this. However, if I opt to go with keeping a different list of hosts in the Production manifests directory things could go pear-shaped pretty much immediately.

The only other method I can think of is to create separate repos for the Dev manifests and modules directories which will allow me to pull the modules updates into Prod while leaving the manifests alone. I can then create a separate repository chain from the /home directory repo, through a new central, bare depot for just the Production manifests and pull in from that seperately. However, I can see this as a non-starter because I'll have already created the git repo under the Production directory. You can't have one directory served by two repos, can you?

Perhaps I would have to place the git repo for each of the manifests and modules directories under those directories.

Is that a viable method? Are there any other, common solutions to this issue? I'm fairly new to git so I'm not versed in how robust it can be.

EDIT:
Link to a diagram which represents what I'm trying to do: [Puppet git repo diagram](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/116457/Visio-Puppet_Production_Diagram_v2.0-sanitized.pdf). You can see why I'd like to keep a separate manifest of nodes under each environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Delete the folder from the repository, add it to .gitignore and then commit the changes. Push that commit to your central bare repo and you are (almost) fine.**

The reason why git shows uncommited changes when you delete the folder is, that you in fact have changed something. You deleted the folder. gitignore doesn't stop that from happening. In fact, if you add a tracked file to `.gitignore`, git will **not** ignore that file (same applies for folders). `.gitignore` only works for untracked files.

So, to untrack files inside a repository, you have to delete them (or at least make git think so) **and** add them to `.gitignore`. You can do that without actually deleting the files from the working directory:

```
git rm --cached <files>
```

The actual files will remain inside the working directory, but `git status` will show them as deleted. If you add them to `.gitignore` at the same time, the files will remain there forever, without git noticing it.

However, if you commit that change and it gets pulled to somewhere else, the files will get deleted because git thinks you actually have deleted them. So you will need to get these files back (This will not make git track these files again as they are added to `.gitignore`):

```
git checkout HEAD~1 <files>
```

That will get the files back on that single repo. You will have to do that for every repo that pulled the commit you made above.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a second repo, why not having a script on Prod which would:

- fetch Dev changes into its own branch on the Prod git repo
- merge that branch Dev on `master`, and then:

  - make the necessary changes specific to prod,
  - add those changes
  - and commit them on `master` of the Prod repo.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following all of this, but if I understand the gist of it is you're saying to create a new branch for Prod. I don't want to merge the changes back into Dev because the Prod repo is actually just a staging repo for pushing into actual development use. We have a platform that serves Dev, Testing, Implementation and Production environments. This Puppet repo is a Dev repo strictly for Puppet. The configs will then be pulled into a repo on another system which will serve the actual platorm. Understand, also, that I am quite new to git (and versioning in general).

Comment: I have a Visio diagram of the configuration I'm shooting for. I'm simply waiting to get a PDF converter installed so I can provide it in a more widely accessible format.